# XSS prevention using AntiXss NuGet

Tags: security, xss, antixsslibrary

I'm trying to prevent cross-site scripting in the backend of my web-application. I was researching and I came accross the AntiXss nuget library. I noticed that there has not been a new release for a while. I was just wodering if it is recommended to user this library or if I should try a different approach.

Answer (score 2):

In .Net versions 4.5 and later, AntiXSS is part of the framework and not a separate library anymore. It is in the `System.Web.Security.AntiXss` namespace, with almost all functionality of the original separate library.

Docs are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.security.antixss.antixssencoder?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Compared to other built-in classes like `HttpUtility`, `AntiXss` is more secure, because it's a whitelist-based encoder, as opposed to blacklisting provided by other classes.

One part that did not make it into the framework is `Sanitizer`, but that was not very useful anyway. There are other libraries for html sanitization if needed (mostly not, it's a special case when dealing with user-supplied html code).

Comment: Is this applicable to .NET 8? or suggest alternate NuGet package for .NET 8